# Individual Preferences for each item in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, preferences, android-preferences

I'm creating my first android app (or attempting to anyway) and i have a question i can't seem to find the answer to.

I would like to allow users to enter a separate set of preferences for each item in a list view.  I have the PreferenceScreen working, but it maintains the same preferences for every item (i.e. changing 1 item results in changes to all others as well).

To give a more detailed example:
Say i have a list of cars:
* Car 1
* Car 2
* Etc...

I would like to be able to click on "Car 1" and get a PreferencesScreen to specify "Make", "Model", "Color" for just that car, instead of having those entries stored globally for the whole app.

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help!

//N

Comment: If you solved it, you may want to create an answer and mark it as "best answer". That'll give you more reputation, get you closer to a badge, and will prevent this question from being listed as "unanswered".

Comment: Thanks for the tip - Wasn't sure the right way to go about posting my solution to myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!!

For any wondering, the solution is that you must call

`getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferenceName(value)` with a value unique to the item you'd like to modify the preferences for (in my case, i used the `ListView` position) prior to calling `addPreferencesFromResource`.

Answer (score 1):

`getPreferenceManager()` deprecated on api 11

Now with honeycom and ICS the method `getPreferenceManager()` is deprecated. Do you know how to do that with the new (PreferenceFragment + Headers)?

Thanks men! It works perfect in earlier versions!

UPDATE: Up to api level 11 is the same method but you have to call it on a Fragment, not on activity.