# Individual preference for each listview item example

Tags: android, listview, preference

What's the easiest way to create separate preferences for each item in an Android listview?  I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217720/individual-preferences-for-each-item-in-a-listview), but it's kind of general.  Could anyone be more specific, possibly show a quick example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you should write some code into your adapter getView method.

You can check the position (with an if-clause) in the method and add a custom desgin/layout depending on the position.
If you use a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout in your ListView item XML you can fill this programmatically in the getView method with all the widgets (edittext, checkbox, etc) you need.